# Continue PHP Script after error?

Tags: php

```
mysql_query("SELECT active...  WHERE account = '".$account."'")

x = 1;
where(x<10){
    if($active == 1){
        mysql_query("UPDATE scriptstatus SET active = '0' WHERE account = '".$account."'");

        /// Script with errors

        x++;
    }
}
mysql_query("UPDATE scriptstatus SET active = '1' WHERE account = '".$account."'");
```

I have a script, but it has errors and that makes the script to stop.

Can I force the script to run until the end?

Comment: Wouldn't error handling, or better yet, fixing the errors be a better solution?

Comment: What kind of errors? Runtime errors? Php errors? sql errors?

Comment: Dublicate entry 'xy' for key 'category'. MySQL, this is purpose

Comment: Don't use `mysql` extension use `PDO` or `Mysqli`.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible, nor is it a good idea. PHP-scripts are terminated upon error.
**The real solution would be to fix the errors instead.**

A side tip: try looking into a proper IDE which informs you on potential problems and errors while you type.

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

```
try {
    /// Script with errors
} catch (Exception $e) {}
```

Comment: the `mysql` extension doesn't throw exceptions.

Comment: @SerjSagan are we talking about the same thing here? `Try/catch` blocks are for exceptions. Errors/Warnings/Notices are totally different. Are you implying that a `try/catch` block can actually catch an Error/Warning/Notice? Check out the note from the link you provided: `Internal PHP functions mainly use Error reporting, only modern Object oriented extensions use exceptions. However, errors can be simply translated to exceptions with ErrorException.`